# counting rows elements and resetting in xslt

Tags: count, xslt-1.0

I have to read from a csv file and generate formatted objects by xslt. The problem that I am facing for two days is that I have to count the rows and when a new value shows up in a row, I have to reset to 1 again.

```
600, A, B, C , D
600, A, B, G, F
600, A, B, E, H
601, A, B, I, K
```

my output is currently like this

```
<Object:<path:A/600/1>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/600/2>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/600/3>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/601/4>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
```

but I expect this:

```
<Object:<path:A/600/1>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/600/2>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/600/3>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
<Object:<path:A/601/1>><Data:<ZoneStart:B><ZoneFinish:C><Id:D>>>
```

creating the counting part and resetting it in xslt 1.0 is killing me. Help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is a declarative functional language.  As long as you are thinking in procedural terms about incrementing and clearing a counter, you're going to be fighting the language, not using it.  Even if you win the fight, which sometimes happens, the result won't be pretty.

Reformulating your apparent requirements in more declarative language, it sounds like they are:

- For each line of input, produce one line of output, copying various fields from the input into appropriate places in the output.
- In each line of output, insert a number, specifically the number 1 plus the number of immediately preceding lines of input which have the same value in the first field of the input.  (So the first line with a given value gets the number 1, the second gets the number 2, etc.)

Your output is already meeting the first requirement.  Your job is to find a functional, declarative way of meeting the second.

The most convenient way to meet the second requirement depends in part on how you are currently iterating over lines of input.  (If your input is really non-XML data, as you show it, then I don't quite see how you are doing anything at all with it in XSLT 1.0; if you're using XSLT 2.0, then you've inadvertently mistagged the question.)

Assuming that the multi-line input you are showing is the content of some element named 'line-by-line-data', I'd handle it in XSLT 1.0 using something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="line-by-line-data">
  <xsl:call-template name="handle-lines">
    <xsl:with-param name="lines" select="string(.)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

And the template `handle-lines` would be a recursive template which chops off one line of input, handles it, and calls itself recursively.

If you're working in XSLT 1.0 and producing the output you show, I'm guessing you already have such a recursive template and only need the following hint.  Add two parameters to the recursive call:  one is the value of field 1, so you can conveniently check whether it has changed; the other is a running count of how many values with that field you have already seen.  This should feel perfectly comfortable even from a purely procedural point of view:  just imagine you're in a language where recursion is the only way to perform iteration.

If you're working in XSLT 1.0 and producing the output you show by some other means, then please show us those means in your question.

Good luck!